# Debugging proxy with SSL MITM for Linux suggestion?

Tags: linux, ssl, proxy

I'm looking for a tool to analyze the traffic between two proprietary apps. It's https and I can control the certs and proxy.

I can't seem to be able to find a free/open source tool to do that, so before I roll my own, any recommendations?

Edit: the few I've seen do not look maintained anymore (Parros?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well [MitmProxy](http://mitmproxy.org/) appears to be fitting the bill!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option would be to terminate the SSL in front of the webserver (rather than on it) and sniff the traffic between the termination and the webserver. Stunnel is ideal for this.

Comment: It's not a webserver.